# Export to CSV not working for ag-grid in angular2

Tags: angular, export-to-csv, ag-grid

I have an ag grid defined in angular2 and its populating data as expected.
But the issue is that when i change the browser language and then do an export to csv,it is still getting imported in english rather than the language selected.
Cam anyone tell me how to fix it?